# Поиск в массиве с возможностью изменения результата (без ссылок)

Tags: php

Требуется написать функцию, через которую можно будет в массиве найти элемент (если несколько таких элементов - то первый), и при необходимости изменить найденный элемент.

Массив такого вида:

```
$myArray = array(
    array(
        "name" => "Tra-ta-ta",
        "id" => 213
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Test name",
        "id" => 25
    ),
    ...
);
```

Я сделал это через ссылки:

```
function &arraySearchByField(
        array &$array, string $fieldName, string $haystack): ?array
    {
        foreach($array as $key => &$arItem)
            if($arItem[$fieldName] == $haystack)
                return $arItem;
        return null;
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть еще варианты решения этой задачи, без ссылок ?

Comment: Можно через дополнительный массив это делать

Comment: К сожалению использовать доп. массив не актуально, т.к. размер массива, в котором ищем достаточно большой. Примерно 150К элементов. И примерно  столько же нужно будет делать запросов на поиск.

Comment: можно так: `foreach( $array as $key => $value){ $array[$key] = $value."123"; }`

Comment: Ищите в функции не элемент, а индекс элемента.